# Makefile conditional OR for definitions

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with 2 ifdef conditions that perform same action when that particular config is selected.

```
     #ifdef A
     //perform C
     #endif /* A */

     #ifdef B
     //perform C
     #endif /* B */

     #ifdef A || B
     //perform C
     #endif
```

Last code block is not working. What is the right way to execute it in Makefile?

Comment: In GNU Make, lines starting with `#` are comments. Should probably fix that.

Comment: Found nothing obvious [in the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html). You could define a PERFORM_C variable, then conditionally `undefine` it in nested `ifndef A`/`ifndef B`, then follow up with a `ifdef PERFORM_C` that performs C. Not great, just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

`#ifdef` and `#endif` are not make conditionals. You probably want:

```
ifdef A
# whatever if make variable A is defined
AB := defined
endif

ifdef B
# whatever if make variable B is defined
AB := defined
endif

ifeq ($(AB),defined)
# whatever if the make variable A or B is defined
endif
```

Note that `ifdef A` is not the same as `ifneq ($(A),)`. So, if you want to test these variables not for definition but for emptiness, you probably want:

```
ifneq ($(A),)
# whatever if the value of make variable A is non-empty
endif

ifneq ($(B),)
# whatever if the value of make variable B is non-empty
endif

ifneq ($(A)$(B),)
# whatever if the value of make variable A or B is non-empty
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using a variant of the technique I proposed in a comment:

```
# De Morgan's Law: (!a && !b) == !(a || b)
ifndef A
  ifndef B
    NEITHER_A_NOR_B_DEFINED :=
  endif
endif

ifndef NEITHER_A_NOR_B_DEFINED
  # Perform C
endif
```